# How to search for a user profile?

Tags: support

I would like to know if a particular user (from another, non stackexchange site, for e.g twitter) has an account here. Searching with `user:<username>` gave a (400 000+ items) list of results. When I clicked on first result, the question page had no mention of  (`ctrl-f <username>`, even after expanding comments)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The drop-down menu in the upper left of the main site:

[image: Main pages's drop-down menu]

Choosing "Users" here takes you to a page where you may search for users by name:

[image: User search interface]

The direct link to that page is https://unix.stackexchange.com/users

Using `user:username` in the search box on the main page is unfortunately not supported.  You can however use `user:me` to find all your own posts and `user:id`, where `id` is a user's numerical ID, to find all posts relating to that user.

So to find all posts that I (Kusalananda) have written, which contains the phrase "for fun", search for [`user:116858 "for fun"`](https://unix.stackexchange.com/search?q=user%3A116858%20%22for%20fun%22)